# cannot import cobertura-maven-plugin in intelliji

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, plugins

I use Intelliji IDEA 2019.3  and  I try to use cobertura-maven-plugin this way

```
       <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${cobertura.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <formats>
                            <format>html</format>
                            <format>xml</format>
                        </formats>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                        <format>xml</format>
                        <rulesets>
                            <ruleset>/pmd-rules.xml</ruleset>
                        </rulesets>
                        <!-- CPD options -->
                        <minimumTokens>20</minimumTokens>
                        <ignoreIdentifiers>true</ignoreIdentifiers>

                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <configLocation>gameoflife-build/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <effort>Max</effort>
                        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <doclet>
                            gr.spinellis.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc
                        </doclet>
                        <docletArtifact>
                            <groupId>gr.spinellis</groupId>
                            <artifactId>UmlGraph</artifactId>
                            <version>4.6</version>
                        </docletArtifact>
                        <additionalparam>
                            -inferrel -inferdep -hide java.* -collpackages
                            java.util.* -attributes -operations
                            -enumerations -enumconstants
                        </additionalparam>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
```

But Intelliji does not find the maven plugin cobertura-maven-plugin, neither the other plugins in the reporting section

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Comment: First please write in english ...otherwise it's hard to understand what you like to ask? Second you are using very old software (IDEA 2019? ... current 2020.3.1..) furthermore what does `But Intelliji does not find the maven plugin `... means? Does the build on plain command line?

Comment: Sorry, I put some latin text because there were too much code. Furthermore, I meant that Maven 3.6.1 is bundled in my intelliji version and that maven does not find this maven plugin. Third, yes, it works on plain command line

Comment: On plain command I have my doubts. that you have called `mvn site` furthermore Upgrade your environment... And what does it mean... Maven does not find this maven plugin? Download error ? Please show that? And please edit the post....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the IDE to be able to resolve the plugin - it must be located inside the local Maven repository. Does it exist there?

To make sure the plugin of the specified version has been downloaded into local Maven repository - you can execute any maven goal of this plugin. Then Maven will download it from the remote Maven repository into your local Maven repository and IDE will be able to resolve it.

Comment: Hello Andrew, thank you, I run mvn install in CLI ang suceeded to download it in the local repository, but in intelliji, I have the following error message : Plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6' not found

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put the right version. I have 2.7 version downloaded. It is resolved. Thanks again